# recreate deleted changes of checked out file -version control system

Tags: controls, version, perforce

I accidently deleted a file from my local view of perforce . that was a checked out file. 
Is there a way to recreate the same file with all the changes i did ?

The view was stored in my local machine

Answer (score 5):

You can check the file out of the repository again but the restoration of your changes will be dependent on your OS and how you deleted it.  If you were, for example, on "OS X" and dragged it to the trash (similarly recycle bin on Windows) you can restore it - but there's no perforce way of getting the changed file back.  Perforce only stores the changes when you check the file in.

Comment: One exception is if you shelved the file/changelist at some point.